# Optimization - maximize minimum of weighted contributions

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a matrix. The constraint is to choose only one element per column. The row sums are then calculated using only the chosen elements. The objective is to maximize the minimum of the row sums. 
Example:

matrix

1 2 3 **4** -> 4

2 **2** **2** 2 -> 2+2 = 4

**3** 1 1 3 -> 3

Thus the minimum of row sums of the chosen elements per column is min(4,4,3) = 3

How to achieve this? I cannot figure out anything else than brute force, which means going through all the column permutations and their row sums. It seems such a simple task that there should be a more efficient way?

Comment: It's NP-hard by reduction from the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (the first and second rows are identical and each contain the input to the partition problem). I suspect that it wouldn't be hard to get a stronger result.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Great observation; I was sitting here trying out different NP-hard problems but didn't think about using partitioning.

Comment: Yeah, duplicate the row n/3 times for a reduction from (restricted) [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), which is strongly NP-hard (partition is only weakly NP-hard).

Comment: Is there any bounds on the number of rows and columns?  Maximum and minimum values in the cells of the maxrix?

Comment: @Jason I wanted to keep it general but the case I needed all the values are non-negative integers. Yet not sure if it helps. Obviously number of columns needs to same or more than number of rows. In my case I can limit the number of columns around 10, which means this is very solvable, does this help to solve it theoretically?

Comment: @David Thanks for the pointer and intuition. I will use brute for now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is strongly NP-hard by reduction from [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) (prepare several duplicate rows consisting of the 3-partition input, one for each desired partition). A mixed-integer programming (MIP) solver likely is not better than brute force in the worst case, but it's easy enough to be worth a try. Suppose that the matrix `a` has `m` rows and `n` columns. In the following integer program, the 0-1 variable `x(i,j)` is `1` if and only if the element `a(i,j)` at row `i` and column `j` is chosen.

```
maximize z
subject to
for all i in [1, m], -z + sum for j in [1, n] of a(i,j) x(i,j) >= 0
for all j in [1, n], sum for i in [1, m] of x(i,j) = 1 (or is it <= 1?)
for all i in [1, m], for all j in [1, n], x(i,j) in {0, 1}
```

Comment: A minor add-on of a special case: if the matrix is square (mxn-matrix, where n==m) this reduces to the Assignment problem, which seems to have a polynomial time solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem.

Comment: There are assignment problem generalizations. This is a maximum assignment problem (which is NP-hard).